# Singapore Visa for Chinese passport holders

Tags: visas, singapore, chinese-citizens

Trying to find information about visa requirements for Chinese nationals to enter Singapore for a short stay visit. The official website mentions that Chinese passport holders require a visa for entry but some pages mention a 96hour visa (VTFT) which includes Chinese citizens with permanent residency in US, UK, Australia  etc

The VTFT is mentioned  in the official website for Indian nationals and CIS passport holders but not for Chinese passport holders.

Does anyone have recent knowledge or experience with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No wonder you're confused. The [Singapore Ministry of Foreign Affairs](https://www.mfa.gov.sg/content/mfa/consular_information/foreigners_visiting_singapore.html) only references Indian nationals being eligible for 96-hour Visa Free Transit Facilities (VFTF). In addition, the [Consular Services in Beijing](https://www.mfa.gov.sg/content/mfa/overseasmission/beijing/visa_information/overview.html) make no mention of it.

However, the [Singapore Airlines visa and immigation requirements page](https://www.singaporeair.com/en_UK/us/travel-info/visas-immigration/requirements/) has a [Get personalised requirements](http://www.iatatravelcentre.com/passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm) link, taking you to IATA Travel Centre and the Timatic tool used by airlines to check passenger visa, passport, and health requirements.  Using the parameters you shared, my search on Timatic indicated that you would not need a visa.

With the details you shared, I queried the Singapore Consulate in New York, singcon_nyc@mfa.sg, which responded:

> The 96-hour visa free transit facility is subject to several specific conditions and entry requirements.  Your airline must also confirm that it is willing to board you under this facility without a Singapore visa.  In addition, final entry into Singapore is at the discretion of the duty officer at the Immigration checkpoint at Changi Airport. Should you wish to check on your eligibility for the 96-hour visa free transit facility, please email your complete detailed itinerary to ICA at ica_feedback@ica.gov.sg for their assessment. The Singapore Immigration and Checkpoints Authority (ICA) would encourage you to apply for a visitor visa to avoid any unnecessary problems upon arrival.
>
> You can visit our website at www.mfa.gov.sg/newyork-consul for information on how to apply for a visitor's visa to Singapore.  The documents required are under Visa Information>Countries Requiring Visas to Enter Singapore>Assessment Level 1 Countries or [this link](http://www.mfa.gov.sg/content/mfa/overseasmission/newyork-consul/visa_information/visaothers/visa1.html). Please note that our processing time is three to five business days plus any mailing time from our receipt of a complete application.
>
> Sincerely, Consulate of Singapore
>
> Our Virtual Assistant AskJamie@MFA is now available on the MFA@SG app  and at our website: www.mfa.gov.sg/newyork-consul
>
> 318 East 48th Street, New York, NY 10017 | 212-223-3331 | www.mfa.gov.sg/newyork-consul

Attachments:
[Visa Applications Checklist](https://www.ica.gov.sg/data/resources/docs/Visitor%20Services/Level%20I%20checklist.pdf)
[Form 14A](https://www.ica.gov.sg/data/resources/docs/Visitor%20Services/Form%2014A.pdf)
[FormV39A](https://www.ica.gov.sg/data/resources/docs/Visitor%20Services/FormV39A.pdf)